# Is objects created using COM, will take heap allocated or stack allocated memory?

Tags: c++

Is objects created using COM(component object model) in C++, will take heap allocated or stack allocated memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap. Call to COM API yields an object and the API provides the caller with a handle to it (this actually corresponds to a pointer). Stack allocation would've made the handle to reference a freed memory once the call to COM API has returned.

Comment: thank you.. I agree that memory for COM objects will get allocated in the heap.. Is there any specific tools to find memory leaks in heap memory and stack allocated memory?? though there are lot of tools available to find the leaks, will those tools find's the leaks in heap or stack memory ?

Comment: There is no such thing as leak in stack memory. Stack memory is automatic, meaning it's being freed automatically when the execution goes beyond the scope where the local (i.e. on-stack) variable is defined.

Comment: @raj Icepack is right. Memory leaks happen when you forget to `free` or `delete` memory you allocated on the heap. There are plenty of tools to detect leaks depending upon what platform you are developing on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the allocation is completely up to the component. When you call CoCreateInstance, COM loads the component and calls its exported DllGetClassObject function to get an IClassFactory implementation to instanciate the class, and then calls IClassFactory::CreateInstance, which of course is implemented by the component. Yes, in C++ it will use the heap. But in C# or any .NET language it will use the garbage-collected heap (although the CCW (COM Callable Wrapper) will use the native heap).

Comment: thank you.. I agree that memory for COM objects will get allocated in the heap.. Is there any specific tools to find memory leaks in heap memory and stack allocated memory?? though there are lot of tools available to find the leaks, will those tools find's the leaks in heap or stack memory ?

Answer (score 0):

THe heap is used to store dynamic memory, as such the memory requested from the DLL will be loaded into the heap. However, I believe calls to the functions in the DLL will still use stack space to execute.

Comment: By definition any function call uses stack space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack. It's unrelated to the actual purpose of that function.